# 32/64-bit Windows/Linux application

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost, 32bit-64bit

I wrote a C++ program which works fine on Linux when it is compiled as a 64-bit executable. I also compiled it as a 32-bit executable on Windows and it crashes with the following message:

```
 boost\boost_1_55_0\boost/test/minimal.hpp(123): exception "std::bad_alloc: bad allocation" caught in function: 'int __cdecl main(int,char *[])'
```

As I have to allocate matrices of integers of the size 20000*20000, I told myself that I probably exceeded the admissible size on 32-bit platforms...

So I compiled it as a 64-bit Windows executable and it works fine. To check that my assumption was the right one, I decided to compile it as 32-bit Linux executable and ... it also works fine? So I have no idea about what the causes of the crash could be...

- 32-bit Windows => crash with standard bad_alloc
- 64-bit Windows => run OK
- 32-bit Linux   => run OK
- 64-bit Linux   => run OK

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Please share [mcve] with us. Note, we don't need full code, we need manufactured [mcve].

Answer (score 6):

32 bit Windows provides you with just under 2GB of address space, with various DLLs, your program, the stack and any other memory you've allocated dotted around in various places. That sometimes means that it doesn't have 1.5GB in a single contiguous chunk to give you.

It's working in the 32 bit linux because I believe that actually provides you with a 3GB address space. Otherwise, it too suffers from the same problems.

Comment: He's definitely hitting a 2GB process limit as you describe.  But just curious, with virtual memory, does "contiguous chunk" actually matter?  Even if the code did successfully allocated the entire 1.5GB chunk, it's going to be allocated across different pages of ram and virtual memory. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: @selbie It needs a contiguous chunk of the virtual address space, how that gets mapped is not relevant.

Comment: @DanMašek - That makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for all, that really explains everything